# Enums and Clojure

Tags: clojure, enums

In the Java/C world, people often use enums. If I'm using a Java library which using enums, I can convert between them and keywords, for example, using `(. java.lang.Enum valueOf e..., (aget ^"[Ljava.lang.Enum;" (. e (getEnumConstants)) i)`, and some reflection. But in the Clojure world, do people ever need anything like an enum (a named integer) ? If not, how is their code structured that they don't need them ? If yes, what's the equivalent ? I sense I'm really asking about indices (for looping), which are rarely used in functional programming (I've used map-indexed only once so far).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For almost all the Clojure code I have seen **keywords tend to be used instead of Enums** they are name-spaced and have all the other useful properties of keywords while being much easier to write. They are not an exact standin because they are more dynamic (as in dynamic typing) than Java enums

as for indexing and looping I find it more idiomatic to map over a sequence of keywords:

```
(map do-stuff [:a :b :c :d] (range))
```

than to loop over the values in an enumeration, which I have yet to find an example of in Clojure code, though an example very likely exists ;-)

Answer (score 19):

As [Arthur points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11856228/214010) - **keywords** are typically used in Clojure in place of enums.

You won't see numbered indexes used much - they aren't particularly idiomatic in Clojure (or most other functional programming languages)

Some other options worth being aware of:

- Use Java enums directly - e.g. `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit/SECONDS`
- Define your own constants with vars if you want numeric values - e.g. `(def ^:const PURPLE 1)`
- You could even implement a macro `defenum` if you wanted more advanced enum features with a simple syntax.

Comment: One potential benefit of an enum system would be ensuring that non-member values are not permitted at runtime. What would be a good way of catering for that in Clojure?

Comment: The clojure way seems to me more about using validation tools / tests for things like that. Check out e.g. Prismatic's Schema library - https://github.com/prismatic/schema

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out. clj-schema seems like another option as well.

Comment: Thanks for providing the Clojure syntax for referencing Java enum members, @mikera.

Comment: Among Clojure validation tools you may now enumerate (wink!) [Clojure Spec](http://clojure.org/guides/spec)

Comment: @luskwater How to spec out an enum with Spec?

Comment: @petrus-theron If you are using keywords, `(s/def :dog/breed #{:labrador :huskador :husky})` is the conventional way to check for "it's got to be one of these values". Any other value could go in the set, whether a Java enum or ints or strings.