# how to handle magic strings in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have code that probes a PostgreSQL database's metadata so I find my code litered with magic strings:

```
(case data_type
   "integer"   ...
   "smallint"  ...
   "bigint"    ...
   "boolean"   ...
   ...
```

where "integer" "smallint" etc. are values returned from queries in the database's metadata tables.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856077/enums-and-clojure) suggests using keywords so perhaps a way to better organize these strings is to define for each such collection of magic strings a pair of encode / decode functions?

E.g.:

```
(defn datatypes-val->kwd [val] ;; return keyword from value
(defn datatypes-kwd->val [kwd] ;; return value from keyword
```

But is it really worth the trouble since it doesn't buy me any type-safety (as would an **enum** in Java)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, it won't buy you "compile time" type-safety for obvious reasons.

You haven't provided much context around the case statement but one design approach I can suggest is using  multi-methods to dispatch on the data-type so that you can easily add new cases for data types. Something like below:

```
(defmulti get-data (fn [type val] type))

(defmethod get-data "integer" [type val]
  ;do something with val and return result
  )

(defmethod get-data "smallint" [type val]
  ;do something with val and return result
  )
```

Comment: I accept your answer but I don't see how multimethods can have any merit when the dispatch logic is trivial. A single function with a case expression seems more tightly bound in my view and just as easy to add new cases. Or am I missing something? (I am new to multimethods)